# Selecting range of character from a set of lines in a file using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I  know below two things,

1. To select a range of line we can use option from **MENU** > **begin/end select**
2. To select a set of characters from a flat-file **CTRL+Shift+Alt and mouse to select a range**

Now my question is, is there a way to do both by combining them?

Comment: This might work better on the [Super User Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com) site, given that it has nothing to directly do with programming.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro, then play?

Comment: No, I have not done using the macro, I am not familiar with it

Comment: What you want is selecting (column mode) just using the keyboard?

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, I have found the answer for myself, Please do review it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself found the answer.

Used group selection along with ctrl+shift+alt and mouse keys to select a specific range of data.